# Show that $||f||_1 = \left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2} $ and $||f||_2 = \left(\int_0^1(1+x)|f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2} $ are equivalent in $C([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**The question is the following**

> For any $f \in C([0,1])$, define
>   $$
> ||f||_1 = \left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2} 
> $$
>   and $$
> ||f||_2 = \left(\int_0^1(1+x)|f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2} 
> $$
>   Show that these two norms are equivalent in $C([0,1])$

**My attempt is the following:**

> Since $f \in C([0,1])$, $f$ is bounded, $f^2$ is bounded, and $xf^2$ is bounded. Also, the definite integrals of all these functions on the interval $[0,1]$ are bounded. We can also assume that $|f(x)| > 0$. Since if the value is 0, then $f$ is the constant zero function, and the two norms are both valued as zero. To prove the two norms are equivalent, it suffices to show that there are constants $c>0$ and $C>0$ such that 
>   $$
> c \left(\int_0^1(1+x)|f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2}\leq \left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2} \leq C \left(\int_0^1(1+x)|f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2}
> $$
>   Derive as
>   \begin{gather*}
>     c \left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^2+\int_0^1x|f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2}\leq \left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2} \leq C \left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^2+\int_0^1x|f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2}
> \end{gather*}
>   Namely, it suffices to find $c_1>0$ and $c_2>0$ such that
>   $$
> c_1\int_0^1|f(x)|^2+c_1\int_0^1x|f(x)|^2\leq \int_0^1|f(x)|^2 \leq c_2\int_0^1|f(x)|^2+c_2\int_0^1x|f(x)|^2
> $$
>   Consider
>
> 1. For the first inequality
>      $$
>        c_1\int_0^1|f(x)|^2+c_1\int_0^1x|f(x)|^2 \leq \int_0^1|f(x)|^2 
>    $$
>      it can be derived as
>      $$
>        c_1\leq \dfrac{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2}{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2+\int_0^1x|f(x)|^2}
>    $$
>      Since all the values are bounded and non-negative, and we have $\int_0^1|f(x)|^2>0$, $c_1$ exists as shown (simply take the equality or anything smaller).
> 2. For the second inequality
>      $$
>    \int_0^1|f(x)|^2 \leq c_2\int_0^1|f(x)|^2+c_2\int_0^1x|f(x)|^2
>    $$
>      it can be derived as
>      $$
>    c_2 \geq \dfrac{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2}{\int_0^1|f(x)|^2+\int_0^1x|f(x)|^2}
>    $$
>      Since all the values are bounded and non-negative, and we have $\int_0^1|f(x)|^2>0$, $c_2$ exists as shown (simply take the equality or anything larger).
>
> Therefore, the two norms are equivalent on $C([0,1])$.

Is my attempt valid? Since the definition says that the $c$ and $C$ must be constant, it confused me whether I have to write out a constant instead of an expression with functions in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier:

Note that on $[0,1]$ we have $|f(x)|^2\leq (1+x)|f(x)|^2\leq 2 |f(x)|^2$. Thus

$$\left(\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx\right)^{1/2}\leq\left(\int_0^1 (1+x)|f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}\leq \left(\int_0^1 2|f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2}=\sqrt{2}\left(\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2\right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Alright, alright man :)